# How to force successful build if post test fails in circleci 1.0

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

In my `circle.yml` file I have a post test that runs after the normal tests, and only when you are building master. I am trying to find a way to alert if this post test succeeds or fails, but have the build pass regardless of success or failure. Note that the build **should** still fail if any of the tests in the **normal test suite** fail. It is only this post test that I wish to see test failure for, but still have the build succeed.

```
test:
  post:
    - |
      if [ master == $CIRCLE_BRANCH ]; then
        npm run extra-tests
      fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*disclaimer: CircleCI Developer Evangelist*

You can do the following:

```
test:
  post:
    - |
      if [ master == $CIRCLE_BRANCH ]; then
        npm run extra-tests || true
      fi
```

The double pipe is an "or" in Bash. If the command to the left succeeds (exit code 0), then we move onto the next line, ending the if block. If it fails, then the command to the right of `||` runs, which always succeeds.

Just be careful as you'll only know if any of these "extra tests" fail by logging into CircleCI's website, viewing the build, and expanding the build output for that section.